# Can you upgrade number of players in Minecraft windows 10/PE realms?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

If I buy a subscription for 2 friends, can I upgrade to 10 friends and vice versa? If so, does it have to be between billing cycles?

I don't want to have to create a new world when I find more friends or pay more than I have to.

[image: Realms selection of number of players in Minecraft Windows 10 / PE]

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to change the size (go from 2 users to 10, or from 10 to
>   2), you will have to cancel the subscription to the Realm, wait until
>   the remaining days expire, and then renew the Realm in the desired
>   size.

https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/2461089#tier

[image: Minecraft 'Renew Your Realm' screen Windows 10/PE]

You could also probably backup/download your world, buy a new realm and upload/import the backup to a new realm that you buy.